# Difference in time python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find the difference between two times such as (05:33, 16:01).  So I know I need to write a script that will do that, and I can do that with these def's:

```
def diff_minutes(start_time, end_time):
    """returns the difference of two inputs

    number, number -> number"""
    return int(start_time - end_time)


def hours_and_minutes_str(hours, minutes):
    """returns a string that represents the time span, including units

    number, number -> str"""
    print (hours, 'hours'  , minutes , "minutes")

def hours_and_minutes_to_minutes(hours, minutes):
    """returns the total minutes of the input

    number, number -> number"""
    return (hours * 60 + minutes)

def minutes_to_hours_and_minutes(minutes):
    """returns two numbers given just a number of minutes

    number, number -> number"""
    return (int(minutes/60), minutes%60)

def extract_hours(tm:'hours:minutes'):
    """returns an integer representing the number of hours

    number, number -> number"""
    return int(tm.split(':')[0])

def extract_minutes(tm:'hours:minutes'):
    """returns an integer representing the number of minutes

    number, number -> number"""
    return int(tm.split(':')[1])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be far easier to just convert them into [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) objects.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have hours and minutes, you can use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) which is pretty straightforward:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> t1 = timedelta(hours=5, minutes=33)
>>> t2 = timedelta(hours=16, minutes=1)
>>> print((t2 - t1).total_seconds())
37680.0
>>> print (t2 - t1)
10:28:00
```

I don't have the actual input you're using, but seems like you know how to map the strings to the creation arguments yourself :)

Generally you can map strings such as `'05'33'` using `split` and `int`:

```
>>> hours, minutes = map(int, '05:33'.split(':'))
>>> hours
5
>>> minutes
33
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... Do you need help in creating the `timedelta` objects' constructing arguments? If so, provide the text you're parsing in your question.

Comment: yeah, I'm not really sure if I need to just copy that into my script, or what.  pretty much at a stand still

Comment: what does your input look like? **add the input and output to your question**

Comment: t1 = timedelta(5:33) t2 = timedelta(16:01) Is this acceptable to use? because it has to be in that format

Comment: 5:33 means nothing in Python. If you mean "5:33" (as a string), you can simply map it to two hours, minutes using (say it's called `_str`): `hours, minutes = map(int, _str.split(':'))`

Comment: @JaredBanton added some code to my answer to help you map it to the arguments. Good luck.

Comment: I recommend using strptime to convert strings to datetime objects.

Comment: @JaredBanton It's a "give and take" int he sense that datetime objects have a point in time while timedlta objects are to be used for... Well, deltas. Either way is fine until more detail is given.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) is what you need here. Specifically, the `strptime` function, which parses a string into a time object.

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '10:33:26'
s2 = '11:15:49' # for example
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
```

That gets you a `timedelta` object that contains the difference between the two times. You can do whatever you want with that, e.g. converting it to seconds or adding it to another `datetime`.

Comment: are the s1 and s2 parts for the input?

Comment: Yes,, you can make them a user input, or you can insert them in your code

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using the standard Python libraries for this. See the [Python reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

```
import datetime

time1 = '05:33'
time2 = '16:01'

format = '%H:%M'
datetime1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, format)
datetime2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, format)

minutes = (datetime2 - datetime1).seconds / 60
```

Comment: why did you include seconds? is that critical for my problem?

Comment: When you subtract two datetimes in Python you get a timedelta. The timedelta object allows you to retrieve days and seconds. Since you seemed to want minutes, based on your code samples, I converted the timedelta.seconds to minutes. Note that having times without dates may do interesting things as you cross day boundaries.